# How can I set ProgId for an electron application?

Tags: windows, electron, registry, nsis, electron-builder

I have created an electron application. Post Windows 8, setting an application as a default mail client needs the registry value at the following location to be changed:

**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto\UserChoice**

Since I am using electron-builder to build my application and using `nsis` target for Windows, where can I create/set/view the `ProgId` for my application? How can I create more than one `ProgId`s if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override the association like that.

The `UserChoice` (and `FileExts`) keys are undocumented and you should not write to them.

Because people [force themselves](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061101-03/?p=29153) and ignore the issue of "[What if two programs did this?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413/)" Microsoft has made it increasingly difficult to programmatically set the default association for types/applications.

If you look inside a `UserChoice` key on recent versions of Windows you will also see a `Hash` value. If the `ProgId` value does not match the hash Windows will ignore your attempt to take over the association. Only the ControlPanel/Settings UI can successfully change the association on these systems.

In enterprise environments you can use [DISM/GPO](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hewagen/making-file-type-associations-enterprise-ready/). Applications installed by normal users cannot do this, your only option is to follow the [Microsoft guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872123(v=vs.85).aspx):

Register your association the normal documented way in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Additionally you can:

- **WinVista & Win7**: You can force yourself by using the `IApplicationAssociationRegistration` interface (Not recommended).
- **Win8**: Ask the user if they want to change their associations and if they confirm you can call [`IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shobjidl/nf-shobjidl-iapplicationassociationregistrationui-launchadvancedassociationui).
- **Win10**: Call `IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI` to [display a help-popup](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/20/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10122-for-pcs/#) instructing the user how they can change their associations.

`LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI` can be used in NSIS v3+ like this:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Win\COM.nsh
Section
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI} ${IID_IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    ${IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI} $0 '("Internet Explorer")' ; Replace with your registered application name
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Registering my association the normal documented way in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT doesn't work in Windows 10. Is there any way in which I can call `IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI` to display a help-popup using Electron (which I guess is basically running C# code as part of an electron application)?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It is not going to make you the default but it will work as its supposed to. If the protocol is not registered by anyone else you will be the default. LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI requires you to register yourself for "Default Programs". Your ...\Capabilities\URLAssociations key will contain a list of protocol to progid mappings the user can select as their default. IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI is just a normal COM interface so yes, it can be called from anything that supports COM...

Comment: Okay. I understood. Thanks for your help.